# Multiplication of two 64 digit nos

Tags: c#

How can I multiply two 64 digit decimal numbers together in C# without overflowing?

Comment: I don't think you can store a 64 digit number in any modern CPU with full accuracy, assuming you mean decimal digits, not binary digits or something else.  If you had TWO 64 digit numbers (assuming starting with a nonzero), then the result would be around 128 digits long (10^64*10^64=10^128).  Ouch.

Comment: You should really give more information than this. Are they integers? That's very important. Digits in what base? Binary? Decimal? Hexadecimal maybe? It matters.

Comment: Sorry for the missing info... Both nos. are decimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need 64 *decimal* digit numbers, and if they are integers, you can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` struct (needs a reference to `System.Numerics.dll` assembly).

```
BigInteger firstNumber = BigInteger.Parse("63518439492097324687235465876298368764576527346564625480");
BigInteger secondNumber = BigInteger.Parse("84890247648975285765484902890273086475254764765147643611");
BigInteger product = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

Comment: Nice.  A class that I'm guessing implements what I was going to suggest (breaking the number up into manageable numbers, and doing the multiplication in parts)

Comment: @Joe Yes, it kind of breaks it up into unsigned 8-bit numbers. They are held in an array of type `byte[]`. I don't know how many CPU multiplications are required for a given size of `BigInteger` (maybe it depends on compile mode and decisions done by the runtime based on actual hardware).

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `decimal` to store the result of multiplication of two `long` numbers.

```
long bigNumber = 12345678L;
long anotherBigNumber = 23456789L;
decimal result = bigNumber * anotherBigNumber;
```

Comment: The multiplication is done with `long` in your example. Even if you cast to `decimal` before you multiply, there may not be enough "space". Try multiplying `1000000000000000L` (fifteen zeroes) with a number of the same size. The result will "wrap-around" if you use `long` multiplication, and it will throw an exception if you use `decimal` multiplication.

Comment: He doesn't say numbers of type `long`. He asked for the multiplication of 64 digited no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the calculation of any number (as long as you want to) IF first that number you convert into string (so two separate string) than get the last number (character) and multiply it with every number from the other character (just like you learned in school) and so on and you add that to you final score number (also as a string). I know this can be done and it would be king difficult logic at the beginning but once you create this function you can multiply any number you want :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are integers, use the BigInteger class in System.Numerics (Reference System.Numerics.dll!)

If not, there is a BigRational class in Codeplex. It was meant to be in System.Numerics but it got kicked. Link:
http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782